# Relate vector of text in dictionary to key in dictionary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have text that I get from a sqlite3 database. I want to compare the similarity of the text by first getting a vector of the text with `CountVectorizer`. I also have a dictionary where I store the text related to the `messageID` (as the dictionary key). How can I relate each vector of text to its `messageID`? e.g. With a vector array that looks like this

```
    [[1 1 0 1 1 0 1]
     [0 1 1 1 1 0 1]
     [0 1 0 1 1 1 1]]
```

I would like to know that `messageID = 0` has vector `[1 1 0 1 1 0 1]`. The vector size and array grow in size with every new message.

I tried putting the dictionary into `CountVectorizer` and tried to evaluate only one message, but neither worked.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity as cosineSimilarity


def getVectorsAndFeatures(strs):
    text = [t for t in strs]
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(text)
    vectorizer.fit(text)
    vectors = vectorizer.transform(text).toarray()
    features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    return vectors, features


text = ['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence',
        'This is the third sentence']
messageDict = {0: 'This is the first sentence', 1: 'This is the second sentence', 2: 'This is the third sentence'}

vectors, features = getVectorsAndFeatures(text)
```

Comment: list item are separated by comma, in your text  you are not providing comma  between different sentence..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example, you have a map between message ID's and sentences

```
>>> text = ['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence',
 'This is the third sentence']
>>> message_map = dict(zip(range(len(text)), text))
>>> message_map
{0: 'This is the first sentence', 1: 'This is the second sentence', 2: 'This is the third sentence'}
```

You then want to count the number of times a text feature appears in each sentence using `CountVectorizer`. You can run the the same analysis as you have:

```py
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer() 
>>> # Learn the vocabulary dictionary and return term-document matrixtransform 
>>> vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(message_map.values()).toarray()
>>> vectors
array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
>>> # get a mapping of the feature associated with each count entry
>>> features = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
>>> features
['first', 'is', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'third', 'this']
```

In the `fit_transform()` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.fit_transform) you have that:

> fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y=None)
>
> Parameters:    raw_documents : iterable
>
> > An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.
>
> Returns:  X : array, [n_samples, n_features]
>
> > Document-term matrix.

This means that each of the vectors corresponds to a sentence in your input text (i.e. `message_map.values()`) in the same order. If you want to map the ID to each vector, you can just do (note that the order is preserved):

```py
>>> vector_map = dict(zip(message_map.keys(), vectors.tolist()))
>>> vector_map
{0: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 1: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

What I believe you are asking, is to fit a corpus and then transform new sentences into a feature count vector. Be aware though, that any new word that is not in the original corpus will be ignored, as shown in this example:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

corpus= ['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer() 
vectorizer.fit(corpus)

message_map = {0:'This is the first sentence', 1:'This is the second sentence', 2:'This is the third sentence'}

vector_map = { k: vectorizer.transform([v]).toarray().tolist()[0] for k, v in message_map.items()}
```

And you obtain:

```
>>> vector_map
{0: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 1: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 2: [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Note that now you have one less feature than previously, because the word `third` is no longer part of the features.

```py
>>> vectorizer.get_feature_names()
['first', 'is', 'second', 'sentence', 'the', 'this']
```

This can be a bit of a problem when calculating the similarity between vectors because you are discarding words that can be useful to discriminate the vectors.

On the other hand, you could use the English dictionary or a subset of it as a corpus and fit that into `vectorizer`. However, the resulting vectors would become more sparse and again, it may cause problems comparing the vectors. But this will depend on the method you use to calculate the distance between vectors.